# Numpy Array to Rust by ndpointer, fails in Windows (works on Linux)

Tags: numpy, rust, ffi

Objective: Pass an np.ascontiguousarray to a Rust function via ctypes. Rust makes various changes to the array in place.  Process continues in Python. the code is tested an runs as expected in a Linux environment (Built in rust-cargo stable on Linux, called from Python 3.8 in Manjaro, 4.19 Kernel), but raises the error: **OSError: exception: access violation reading 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF** (see below for Windows build conditions)

The (simplified) code:

```
#python:
import ctypes
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer
import numpy as np

ext_lib_path = "extlib.dll" #in the windows version
ext_lib = ctypes.CDLL(ext-lib-path)
process_array = ext_lib.proc_array
process_array.argtypes = [ ndpointer(ctypes.c_double), ctypes.c_size_t ]
process_array.restype = ctypes.c_size_t

#other code builds np array of 2xn float64, called src_ar
c_array = np.ascontiguousarray(src_ar)
result_count = process_array(c, c.size)
```

Actual rust function is more involved.  This tiny snip is enough to prove it works in Linux, while raising the exception in Windows

```
//Rust:
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn proc_array(data: &mut [f64], count : usize) -> usize {
    println!("In Windows Array Test: received {} items...", count);
    let e = count - 1;
    // Next Line is where the exception is raised:
    println!("Start & End: {:.4}, {:.4}", data[0], data[e]);
    data[0] += 200.0;
    data[e] *= 2.0;
    println!("Start & End: {:.4}, {:.4}", data[0], data[e]);
    let pairs : usize = count / 2;
    pairs
}
```

I know that the exception is raised in the line where it first tries to read `data[0]` (i ran also some even shorter versions of this involving also eg `let x :f64 = data[0]` to demonstrate it is the first read operation on `data[0]` that raises the exception.)

Also known:
The windows version of this is compiled under rust-cargo in windows.
The behavior is the same if compiled with the windows-gnu, or the windows-msvc toolchains.
In all cases: `print(hex(c.__array_interface__['data'][0]))` shows the address of `c_array` is for example `0x225108514c0`, something expected, certainly not 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF (which points to the MOON, certainly nowhere in my 32GB of ram...).

My conclusion is somehow Python in windows is passing the pointer differently than in Linux and I need to pass this pointer differently when under windows, but I have found nothing that answers this exact point in my searches.

Comment: The `data` parameter to your rust function should be a pointer to `f64`, _not_ a slice. See: http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/slice_arguments/

Comment: There's also a mismatch between return types. The Rust code returns a `u32`, but the Python code declares `process_array.restype = ctypes.c_size_t`.

Comment: And straight passing a numpy array assuming it's a pointer to a C-style array seems a tad optimisitic as well. [as_ctypes](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.ctypeslib.html#numpy.ctypeslib.as_ctypes) might be a good idea.

Comment: These comments all helped a lot.  As soon as I have enough points, I will come back and add upvotes!

Answer (score 1):

Following Jmb's suggestion of http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/slice_arguments/
and

- https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/fn.from_raw_parts_mut.html,
- 'help' responses from the Rust compiler

the following accomplishes the stated goal of *Pass the np.ascontiguousarray to Rust such that it can be mutated with the changes available to the python caller*, with the same code serving a windows caller and a linux caller

```
struct Node {
    x : f64,
    y : f64,
    //  ... (real version has additional fields used elsewhere)
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn array_test(dptr: *mut f64, count : usize) -> usize {
    println!("In Windows Array Test: received {} items...", count);
    let data : &mut[f64] = unsafe {
        assert!(!dptr.is_null());
        std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(dptr, count)
    };
    let pairs : usize = count / 2;

    // populate the structs
    let mut nodes : Vec<Node> = Vec::with_capacity(pairs); 
    for i in (0..count).filter(|x| (x % 2 == 0)) {
        nodes.push(Node { x: data[i], y : data[i+1] } );
    }
    // actual detail of the changes made to the data 
    // not relevant to this question    
    
    // write x & y's back to the data buffer
    for i in 0..pairs {
        data[i * 2] = nodes[i].x;
        data[(i * 2) + 1] = nodes [i].y;
    }
    //  placeholder return:
    pairs
}
```

This tested in the two environments Win 10, plain linux (within the systems I use... sorry I do not have the ability to test this approach on other configurations just now)